# Navigation bar keeps hiding my body content

Tags: html, css

I was trying to build a web page and I started with some css I found online .
When I'm trying to add new div in the body it keeps appearing under the navbar.
I know it's related to position but I couldn't figure out a solution.

```
wrapper{
background: #171c24;
position: fixed;
width: 100%;
}
.wrapper nav{
position: relative;
display: flex;
max-width: calc(100% - 200px);
margin: 0 auto;
height: 70px;
align-items: center;
justify-content: space-between;
}
nav .content{
display: flex;
align-items: center;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/24d1keht/

Sorry , I couldn't post all the code here. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Set the `margin-top` property of your body to the height of your navigation bar and then set the absolute position of your navigation bar to the very top of the page (so it isn't affected by the new margin), with the `top` property.

The CSS would look like this:

```
body {
    margin-top: 0;
}

.wrapper {
    top: 0;
}
```